# bash (awk) split string

Tags: bash, awk

I have a string:

```
b="123 321 || 431543 653 || 039 ||"
```

I use " || " as separator. I want to separate it in 3 strings:

```
123 321
431543 653
039 ||
```

When I try to split it with bash:

```
for element in ${b//" || "/ } ; do echo $element; done
```

The result:

```
123
321
431543
653
039
||
```

When I use awk - I have same result (I get only the first number, but result is expected to be "123 321"):

```
echo $b |awk '{split($0,a," || "); print a[1]}'
123
```

Comment: Missing quotes. Use `printf "$b"` or `printf "%s\n" "$b"`.

Comment: I used echo. will correct with initial usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to escape pipe char

```
$ awk -v b="123 321 || 431543 653 || 039 ||" 'BEGIN{print split(b,a," \\|\\| ")}'
3
```

note that size is not 4 but 3, since the last delimiter is missing the trailing space char.  Perhaps you should make the wrapping space chars optional.

Comment: Yes, escaping was the key! the working solution: `echo $b |awk '{split($0,a," \\|\\| "); print a[2]}'`

Comment: @TelinovDima: I suggest: `echo "$b" | awk -F ' \\|\\| *' '{split($0,a); print a[2]}'`

Comment: The 3rd arg for split() is a regexp, not a string, so use regexp delimiters and then, in addition to that just being the right thing to do, you won't have to double-escape the pipes to handle the first parse required to convert a string to a regexp: `split(b,a,/ \|\| /)`. Obviously you could alternatively just set FS and avoid calling split(): `awk -F ' [|][|] *' '{print NF, $2}'`